# Serializing without XmlInclude

Tags: c#, xml, reflection, serialization

I'm deserializing a class called `Method` using .NET Serialization. `Method` contains a list of objects implementing `IAction`. I originally used the [`[XmlInclude]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx) attribute to specify all classes which implement `IAction`.

But now, I'd like to change my program to load all the dll's in a directory and strip out the classes which implement `IAction`. Then users can deserialize files which contain their actions implementing `IAction`.

I don't control the classes which implement `IAction` anymore, therefore I can't use [`[XmlInclude]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx).

Is there a way to set this attribute at runtime? Or have a similar attribute set for the implementing class?

```
public class Method
{
    public List<Actions.IAction> Actions = new List<Actions.IAction>();
}

public interface IAction
{
    void DoExecute();
}

public static Type[] LoadActionPlugins(string pluginDirectoryPath)
{
    List<Type> pluginTypes = new List<Type>();

    string[] filesInDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(pluginDirectoryPath, "*.dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (string pluginPath in filesInDirectory)
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly actionPlugin = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(pluginPath);
        Type[] assemblyTypes = actionPlugin.GetTypes();
        foreach (Type type in assemblyTypes)
        {
            Type foundInterface = type.GetInterface("IAction");
            if (foundInterface != null)
            {
                pluginTypes.Add(type);
            }
        }
    }

    return pluginTypes.Count == 0 ? null : pluginTypes.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

XmlSerializer has a constructor that accepts an array of types that will be accepted when deserializing:

```
public XmlSerializer(
   Type type,
   Type[] extraTypes
);
```

You should be able to pass your array of assemblyTypes as the second argument.

Answer (score 6):

You can an array of types into the Xml Serializer as David Norman has shown. One huge word of caution. Every time you do this a new xml serializer is built and compiled. If you do this a lot you will have a huge memory leak and performance hog on your hand.

This is a huge memory and performance hog, make sure you only do this once.
You can resolve this by caching your xml Serializer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Snippet from MSDN:

> Dynamically Generated Assemblies To increase performance, the XML
>   serialization infrastructure dynamically generates assemblies to
>   serialize and deserialize specified types. The infrastructure finds
>   and reuses those assemblies. This behavior occurs only when using the
>   following constructors:
>
> XmlSerializer..::.XmlSerializer(Type)
>
> XmlSerializer..::.XmlSerializer(Type, String)
>
> If you use any of the other constructors, multiple versions of the
>   same assembly are generated and never unloaded, which results in a
>   memory leak and poor performance. The easiest solution is to use one
>   of the previously mentioned two constructors. Otherwise, you must
>   cache the assemblies in a Hashtable, as shown in the following
>   example.