# Serialize nested interface

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

how can i serialize this class?

```
public class MyClass    {
    IInterface MyProperty { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Hi aron, it is customary to add a note to a question or answer if it has been updated e.g. EDIT: blah, blah, blah because of blah blah blah. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a setter to MyProperty as Xml serialization rules mandate that serialization must be able to round-trip i.e. it must be able to get the property for serialization, then set the property for deserialization.

Comment: sorry about misunderstanding, i need a way to serialize property which is interface, instantiated of course

Comment: Sorry was being a bit literal there. If it's an interface you'll need to follow Thomas's answer, but you will still need to have a setter on your property.

Answer (score 1):

As chibacity said, you need to add a setter to the property. You also need to add the `XmlInclude` attribute to the property to specify the possible implementing types, otherwise the `XmlSerializer` won't know what type to instantiate when deserializing

Answer (score 0):

The XmlSerializer cannot serialize interfaces.

If you know the concrete types you will be dealing with in advance then you can use the `XmlInclude` approach.  If not then there have been a few discussions about how to handle this:

- [XML serialization of interface
  property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333864/xml-serialization-of-interface-property)
- [XmlSerialization with Interfaces](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/bac96f79-82cd-4fef-a748-2a85370a8510/)
- [Serializing without XmlInclude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370291/serializing-without-xmlinclude)

Answer (score -2):

Make the class that implements IInterface Serializable like you normally would and it will all work.