# XML Serialize generic list of serializable objects with abstract base class

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

Any good sample on how to serialize list of generic objects with abstract base class. Samples with non abstract base class are listed in [XML Serialize generic list of serializable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212742/xml-serialize-generic-list-of-serializable-objects). My base class is similar to [Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.task.aspx)

Comment: Agree with @Dmitry. Alternative answer can be found in Serializing without XmlInclude http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370291/serializing-without-xmlinclude

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is often useful to have abstract classes with several derived types to allow use of strongly typed lists and the such.

For example you might have a DocumentFragment class which is abstract and two concrete classes called TextDocumentFragment and CommentDocumentFragment (this example from Willis).

This allows the creation of a List property which can contain objects only of those two types.

If you attempt to create a WebService that returns this list you get an error but this is easy to get around with the code below....

```
[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(TextDocumentFragment))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(CommentDocumentFragment))]
public abstract class DocumentFragment {
...}
```

The XmlInclude attributes tell the class that it might be serialized to those two derived classes.

This generates an attribute in the DocumentFragment element specifying the actual type, as below.

```
<DocumentFragment xsi:type="TextDocumentFragment">
```

Any additonal properties specific to the derived class will also be included using this method.

Answer (score 13):

Another alternative is to use the `XmlElementAttribute` to move the list of known types to the generic list itself...

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public abstract class Animal
{
    public int Weight { get; set; }    
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public int FurLength { get; set; }    
}

public class Fish : Animal
{
    public int ScalesCount { get; set; }    
}

public class AnimalFarm
{
    [XmlElement(typeof(Cat))]
    [XmlElement(typeof(Fish))]
    public List<Animal> Animals { get; set; }

    public AnimalFarm()
    {
        Animals = new List<Animal>();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        AnimalFarm animalFarm = new AnimalFarm();
        animalFarm.Animals.Add(new Cat() { Weight = 4000, FurLength = 3 });
        animalFarm.Animals.Add(new Fish() { Weight = 200, ScalesCount = 99 });
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AnimalFarm));
        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, animalFarm);
    }
}
```

... which will also result in  a better looking XML output (without the ugly `xsi:type` attribute)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<AnimalFarm xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Cat>
    <Weight>4000</Weight>
    <FurLength>3</FurLength>
  </Cat>
  <Fish>
    <Weight>200</Weight>
    <ScalesCount>99</ScalesCount>
  </Fish>
</AnimalFarm>
```

Comment: if you wan't to keep the Animals element you can use the XmlArrayItemAttribute instead.